# Реализация метода default <T> T[] toArray(T[] array)

Tags: java, коллекции, generics, classcastexception

Пытаюсь построить свой JCF (балуюсь, чтобы лучше разобраться в коллекциях).

Создал класс `MyList<E>`, который реализует интерфейс `Collection<E>`, и возникла необходимость реализовать дефолтные методы `retainAll(Collection<?> c)` и `<T> T[] toArray(T[] array)`.

Вроде как получилось, но хотелось бы узнать у знатоков, нельзя ли в методе `<T> T[] toArray(T[] array)`, каким-нибудь другим образом создать новый массив большего размера?

Я пытался создать новый типа `Object[]`, а потом привести его к `T[]`, но вылетает `ClassCastException`.

Мое решение:

```
    @Override
    default boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        removeIf(element -> !c.contains(element));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    default <T> T[] toArray(T[] array) {
        if (array.length != size()) {
            array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + (size() - array.length));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
            array[i] = (T)get(i);
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: @user7860670 Вы имеете в виду: `T[] newArr = new T[capacity]` ? Так я же не могу создавать массив, используя тип дженерика

Comment: у Вас в методе `toArray` на входе массив объектов типа T и на выходе массив объектов типа T... так и надо? ничего не напутали? в чем смысл приводить `T[ ]` к `T[ ]`?

Comment: @МихаилРебров Да, на входе `T[] array` и на выходе должен быть тоже `T[] array` . Просто если размер коллекции больше, чем переданный массив, то мне нужно создать новый массив и скопировать туда элементы коллекции. `(T)get(i);` - это нужно, поскольку MyList<E>, и без приведения компилятор ругается

Comment: я дополнил ответ. Извиняюсь что так долго. Занят на работе был + писал вам много букаф. Как проверите - отпишитесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Создание массива параметризируемого типа(дженерика) в общем виде

Можно попробовать создать массив с помощью рефлексии

Имеем `object` с параметризируемым типом(дженериком) `T`:

```java
T object;
```

Имея такие вводные можем создать массив элементов данного типа следующим образом:

```java
T[] arr = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                    object.getClass().getComponentType(), // получаем тип из класса объекта
                    size // указываем размер массива
                );
```

#### Назначение метода toArray

Метод `toArray` создан для приведения коллекции к массиву того же типа.
В данный метод мы передаем ссылку на массив, в который мы будем записывать данные коллекции.
Если в массиве недостаточно места, то мы создаем новый и записываем его на место старого.
Если в массиве места больше чем требуется, то мы ставим нулевой элемент(`null`) как метку окончания данных.

#### Рассмотрим имеющиеся реализации метода toArray

Для того, чтобы сделать правильную реализацию данного метода неплохо было бы заглянуть, а как они сами предлагают это сделать, на примере реализаций из `ArrayList` и `LinkedList`.

**Реализация toArray(T[] a) в классе ArrayList**

```java
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size)
        // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
        return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
    System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;
    return a;
}
```

Напоминаю, что мы рассматриваем реализацию ArrayList и как следует из названия - это реализация интерфейса `List<E>` на основе массива, что важно в контексте дальнейшего рассмотра.

Для хранения элементов списка в классе `ArrayList` используется поле elementData.

Сначала мы проверяем, достаточный ли размер у переданного массива, чтобы мы могли поместить в него имеющиеся элементы.

```java
if (a.length < size)
```

Если размера массива недостаточно, то мы с помощью утилитарного класса `Arrays` делаем копию массива `elementData` c тем же размером и с указанием типа переданного массива (`a.getClass()`)

```java
return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
```

В противном случае мы копируем **все** элементы массива `elementData` в массив `а` (как и планировалось), **начиная с самого начала**(в данном используемый метод позволяет указать место с которого можно начать копировать и место в которое следует копировать, а также количество этих элементов).
Копируем мы с помощью утилитарного метода `arraycopy` в классе `System`

```java
System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
```

Далее мы проверяем, а не больше ли переданный массив нашего списка

```java
if (a.length > size)
```

Если у переданного массива размер больше необходимого, то мы ставим null в след за скопированными элементами, чтобы при итерации можно было найти конец данных и не отхватить Exception в лицо

```java
a[size] = null;
```

**Реализация toArray(T[] a) в классе LinkedList**

```java
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size)
        a = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                a.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
    int i = 0;
    Object[] result = a;
    for (LinkedList.Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        result[i++] = x.item;

    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;

    return a;
}
```

Как и в прошлом случае мы сначала проверяем, достаточный ли размер у переданного массива.

```java
if (a.length < size)
```

Если размер массива недостаточен, то мы с помощью рефлексии создаем новый массив с указанным типом данных и нужным нам размером и сохраняем ссылку на него в переменную `a`

```java
a = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
           a.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
```

Отмечу, что в данной реализации используется именно тот способ, который я предлагал изначально.

В отличии от первой реализации, на данном этапе у нас есть просто пустой массив достаточного размера, в то время как в прошлой мы уже возвращали новый массив для одного из обрабатываемых кейсов.

Далее нам необходимо переложить все элементы в данный массив.

Для начала мы определяем переменную в которой будет храниться индекс итерируемого элемента, т.к. в связанном списке при итерации мы имеем только ссылку на предыдущий и на следующий элемент.

```java
int i = 0;
```

Далее мы создаем переменную `result` и кладем туда ссылку на массив `a`

```java
Object[] result = a;
```

Вот тут уже нужна пояснительная бригада.
Делается это по всей видимости для того чтобы не заморачиваться с приведением типов.
Поэтому дабы избежать проблем и заморочек мы просто создадим еще одну ссылку, только уже объявленную как `Object[]`.
И туда уже нам будет разрешено класть элементы списка без какого бы то ни было приведения типов.
Причем по сути мы будем работать с тем же самым массивом.
Только условия попадения в него будут помягче:)
Такие вот финты ушами можно найти в исходниках `java.lang`
По сути разработчики `JDK` просто перекладывают ответственность на то, что вы кладете в список на Вас (а что им еще делать?).

Далее мы копируем элементы связанного списка в массив, используя при этом переменную `result`

```java
for (LinkedList.Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
    result[i++] = x.item;
```

Здесь также стоит остановиться и рассмотреть все поподробнее.

Сначала мы в качестве итератора берём ноду связанного списка и инициализируем итератор ссылкой на первый элемент.

```java
LinkedList.Node<E> x = first;
```

В качестве условия выхода из цикла мы используем обычную проверку на null.

```java
x != null;
```

Она рано или поздно там появится, потому что у последнего элемента в списке ссылка на следующий элемент списка будет отсытствовать и равна `null`, там мы и остановимся.

Ну и в качестве выражения перехода, мы используем получение ссылки на следующий элемент связанного списка

```java
x = x.next
```

Так поочереди, получая элемент за элементом мы обойдём весь список.

И получая каждый элемент списка мы кладем его значение в массив

```java
result[i++] = x.item;
```

- Как и говорилось раньше используется переменная result, но по сути мы работаем с тем же `а`
- мы в одну строку и получаем значение индекса элемента и увеличиваем его на единицу(он это позволяет, почему бы не воспользоваться?)

Далее как и в первом варианте мы помечаем конец данных нулевым элементом

```java
if (a.length > size)
    a[size] = null;
```

и возвращаем массив

#### Ваша реализация

Для начала укажу на некоторые недочеты Вашей реализации.

Вот что Вы используете при копировании массива:

```java
array.length + (size() - array.length)
```

Зачем так сложно?
Если мы опустим скобки (а они тут необязательны), то мы получим просто `size()` (`array.length - array.length = 0`)

Т.к. у меня нет кода всей реализации класса, я не могу за Вас полностью написать какую-то ультимативную реализацию Вашего метода `toArray`, как и не смогу проверить ее работоспособность, но я могу рассмотреть примеры и обратить внимание на идеи и приемы, которые используются в вышеуказанных реализациях и выдвинуть пару предложений по реализации.

##### Вариант

Вы можете воспользоваться тем же финтом ушами с подменой типа массива и написать что-то вроде этого:

```java
@Override
default <T> T[] toArray(T[] array) {
    if (array.length != size()) {
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, size());
    }
    // сохраняем ссылку на массив в переменную с менее строгим типом
    Object[] result = array; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        //работаем с подменой без приведения
        result[i] = get(i); 
    }
    // но возвращаем переданную ссылку
    return array;
}
```

Самому интересно сработает или нет.
Как попробуете - отпишитесь!

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ!

Comment: @supervitas, вот теперь дополнил

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ваш отклик! Да, действительно `array.length + (size() - array.length)` с этим моментом - опростофилился))) Да, ваш вариант работает! Т.е. нужно было привести к типу `Object`.

Comment: @supervitas, отлично! Удачи Вам!